# Xamarin iOS creating drop down list

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I would like to make a Facebook like app which has a dropdown list when clicked on the toolbar button, the view then will have a table view and user can choose one of them then change the view of the `MainViewController`. So far, I've just added the toolbar items but yet not knowing how to implement the bit that draws a new viewcontroller, please help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is not a built-in control in iOS (for iPhone). There is the the popover control for iPad ([see here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/Popovers.html)), but that is only for the iPad.

I did a quick search and found [FPPopover](https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover), but I have not used it before. I'd start there, otherwise what you're looking for is an "implementation of popover control for iPhone".

Comment: As of iOS 9 and later, iPhone can use UIPopover :)